# Python matplotlib & Plotly: Data does not fit as an exponential function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, curve-fitting

Though I face the same problem with [Exponential curve fit will not fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099026/exponential-curve-fit-will-not-fit), I fail to solve my problem in the same way. Here's my code:

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py

from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pylab

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = genfromtxt('D:\\FT_VINCENT.csv', delimiter=',')

# print(data)

x = np.asarray([a[0] for a in data])
y = np.asarray([a[1] for a in data])

def exponential_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(b * x) + c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponential_func, x, y, p0=(0.80, -0.05, 1.66), maxfev=2000)

xdata = np.linspace(5, 25, 1000)
ydata = exponential_func(xdata, *popt)

plt.plot(x ,y, 'o', xdata, ydata)
plt.xlabel('U')
plt.ylabel('Gust Factor')
pylab.title('FT_VINCENT')
ax = plt.gca()
fig = plt.gcf()
py.plot_mpl(fig, filename='Exponential-Fit-with-matplotlib')
```

[image]

But when I fit the curve using plotly online with the same parameter, it works totally fine.

[image]

The parameter I use in Python is the same in online plotly. Can anyone help me out?

Edit：x

```
5.541666667
5.583333333
5.591666667
5.716666667
5.816666667
5.875
5.966666667
6
5.95
5.891666667
5.85
5.858333333
5.925
6.05
6.208333333
6.258333333
6.258333333
6.333333333
6.416666667
6.533333333
6.65
6.75
6.85
6.816666667
6.708333333
6.566666667
6.466666667
6.416666667
6.283333333
6.133333333
6
5.875
5.825
5.85
5.833333333
5.808333333
5.808333333
5.858333333
5.841666667
5.783333333
5.85
5.916666667
5.925
5.908333333
5.875
5.808333333
5.833333333
6
6.116666667
6.108333333
6.141666667
6.283333333
6.316666667
6.266666667
6.358333333
6.491666667
6.625
6.766666667
6.733333333
6.625
6.625
6.75
6.816666667
6.783333333
6.891666667
7.041666667
6.966666667
6.816666667
6.783333333
6.8
6.858333333
6.866666667
6.791666667
6.691666667
6.725
6.816666667
6.775
6.708333333
6.816666667
6.941666667
6.908333333
6.858333333
6.858333333
6.941666667
6.958333333
6.883333333
6.766666667
6.6
6.516666667
6.55
6.591666667
6.683333333
6.791666667
6.875
7.083333333
7.375
7.641666667
8.041666667
8.541666667
9.083333333
9.65
10.025
10.31666667
10.64166667
11.10833333
11.70833333
12.00833333
12.10833333
12.51666667
12.86666667
12.925
12.99166667
13.11666667
13.24166667
13.35
13.48333333
13.58333333
13.48333333
13.45833333
13.66666667
13.65
13.41666667
13.34166667
13.30833333
13.19166667
13.09166667
13.00833333
13
13.025
12.975
12.93333333
12.775
12.7
12.79166667
12.88333333
13.05
13.30833333
13.64166667
13.88333333
14.08333333
14.06666667
14.1
14.35833333
14.69166667
15.01666667
15.28333333
15.525
15.65
15.625
15.73333333
15.99166667
16.05833333
16.20833333
16.39166667
16.39166667
16.31666667
16.15833333
16.04166667
15.96666667
16.05
16.25833333
16.21666667
16.06666667
16.04166667
15.98333333
15.85833333
15.675
15.41666667
15.14166667
14.91666667
14.7
14.26666667
13.80833333
13.54166667
13.425
13.225
13
12.875
12.91666667
13.11666667
13.26666667
13.19166667
13.19166667
13.31666667
13.5
13.73333333
13.85
14.03333333
14.11666667
14.23333333
14.425
14.50833333
14.725
15.225
15.58333333
15.70833333
15.65
15.58333333
15.525
15.3
15.23333333
15.04166667
14.7
14.38333333
13.88333333
13.35833333
12.875
12.43333333
12.15833333
11.79166667
11.54166667
11.45
11.325
11.375
11.41666667
11.34166667
11.30833333
11.25833333
11.15833333
11.14166667
11.11666667
11.1
10.93333333
10.78333333
10.73333333
10.63333333
10.55833333
10.49166667
10.46666667
10.45833333
10.40833333
10.35
10.29166667
10.25833333
10.16666667
9.883333333
9.6
9.275
8.95
8.633333333
8.241666667
7.9
7.666666667
7.458333333
7.2
6.891666667
6.683333333
6.633333333
6.5
6.3
6.108333333
6.066666667
```

y:

```
1.894736842
1.880597015
1.877794337
2.116618076
2.080229226
2.059574468
2.027932961
2.016666667
2.033613445
2.053748232
2.136752137
2.13371266
2.109704641
2.066115702
2.27114094
2.252996005
2.252996005
2.226315789
2.197402597
2.158163265
2.120300752
2.088888889
2.058394161
2.068459658
1.893167702
1.934010152
2.319587629
2.337662338
2.387267905
2.445652174
2.5
2.553191489
2.575107296
2.564102564
2.571428571
2.582496413
2.117647059
2.099573257
2.105563481
2.126801153
2.102564103
2.078873239
2.075949367
2.08180536
2.093617021
2.117647059
3.017142857
2.933333333
2.04359673
2.04638472
2.39348711
2.339522546
2.327176781
2.345744681
2.311926606
2.264441592
2.218867925
2.172413793
2.183168317
2.218867925
2.203773585
2.162962963
2.141809291
2.152334152
2.118500605
2.073372781
2.09569378
2.376528117
2.388206388
2.382352941
2.362089915
2.359223301
1.973006135
2.00249066
2.527881041
2.493887531
2.509225092
2.534161491
2.493887531
2.448979592
2.46079614
2.47873633
2.47873633
2.448979592
1.322155689
1.670702179
2.113300493
2.166666667
2.194373402
2.183206107
2.852085967
2.812967581
2.76809816
2.734545455
2.654117647
2.793220339
1.976008724
2.536787565
2.856585366
2.686238532
2.528497409
2.433915212
2.365105008
2.292873923
2.223555889
2.152313167
2.098542679
2.081211287
1.973368842
1.919689119
1.918762089
2.016677357
2.081321474
2.061674009
2.04494382
2.024721879
2.009815951
2.024721879
2.028482972
1.997560976
1.860805861
1.893167702
1.903810119
1.908578585
1.970941251
1.985996181
1.99871877
2.323076923
2.318618042
2.327552987
2.335051546
2.050880626
2.133858268
2.118566775
2.103492885
2.076628352
2.058860363
2.221136225
2.182472989
2.15147929
2.154028436
2.14893617
2.277423099
2.22575156
2.177580466
2.139585605
2.112721417
2.095846645
2.0992
2.084745763
2.051068265
2.042553191
2.023650386
2.001016777
1.677681749
1.758937692
1.776173285
1.789090909
1.797494781
1.794392523
1.771399282
1.81294964
1.829875519
1.907532468
1.914494265
1.929584866
1.894736842
1.926486486
1.961474959
1.991061453
2.020408163
2.081775701
2.150875075
2.193230769
2.324022346
2.359168242
2.4
2.423300971
1.796129032
2.287166455
2.261306533
2.274162982
2.274162982
2.25281602
2.222222222
2.184466019
2.166064982
2.137767221
2.12514758
2.107728337
1.802426343
2.21941413
2.186757216
2.114942529
2.06631016
2.049867374
2.057507987
2.06631016
2.074074074
2.104575163
2.113785558
2.140720222
1.489795918
1.522595597
1.577430972
1.639426076
1.700970874
1.761394102
1.825908156
1.882685512
2.044765343
2.061135371
2.08388521
2.074725275
1.997080292
2.010286554
2.016212233
2.025166543
2.043315907
2.046372476
2.050974513
2.054054054
2.085365854
2.114374034
2.124223602
2.144200627
2.017363852
2.030182685
2.035031847
2.036653386
2.04643715
2.057971014
2.069635628
2.076360682
2.095081967
2.155143339
2.21875
2.296495957
1.832402235
1.8996139
1.989888777
2.075949367
2.139130435
2.198882682
2.277777778
2.379685611
2.453865337
2.472361809
2.523076923
2.603174603
1.866302865
2.043956044
```

Comment: Can you please share the data? Now I can't keep myself from trying your example.

Comment: @Bazingaa I have added the data.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it during the day. May be you already get some answer by then but I will update you here.

Comment: What is the issue here? The two plots look exactly the same to me except a different x range on the plots

Comment: @kevinkayaks No, they are not.  If I set xdata=np.linspace(0, 1000, 1000), I find it a straight line. In fact, as x goes to infinity, y should be close to c.

Comment: So what *is* `c` in both cases? Do you also have the plotly code available?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The function I use to fit both curves is the same. a=0.80, b=-0.05, c=1.66.

Comment: Those are the starting values, not the fitted parameters. The fitted parameters will be different from the starting values, because that's the hole idea behind a *fit*.